# wp_options Table keeps growing

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, options

wp_options Table keeps growing. I few days ago this issue started on my blog. I though it was a plugin problem but couldn't find a way a out so I delete it everything, wp, database, all. New installation with plugins what I really needs the problem comes again.

database fix, optimize, delete Transient then looks to be fine again.

```
fusion_builder_settings 276072
fusion_options 46450 
brainstrom_bundled_products 37642 
asp_updates 35254 
rewrite_rules 28345 
dfrapi_product_networks 26361 
smile_info_bar_styles 13385 
smile_modal_styles 12748 
wp_user_roles 10351 
wpseo_titles 9071
```

THIS above autoload time wp_options

after few hours its growing again.

I think its still a plugin issue but how to find out which one is causing the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what the code block in your question represents, is it the size of the table, or the size of the entries, and if so, are those the entries? If they are the entries, then the prefixes kind of tell you which plugins they are, e.g. `fusion_builder_settings` is probably a plugin called fusion builder, additionally, not all those numbers are the same. As an aside, is the size of the table causing problems? Or is it just not to your liking?

Comment: When I clean/optimize the table then size shrink to about mb1.56 after 20min its growing to 35mb after one day would more then 1GB so there is something really wrong but I can't find out what that it i. I have the same installation on 2 different servers but only on 1 server is this problem appears.

Comment: How to find out which plugin is causing the problem?

Comment: are these the quantity of options, or the size of individual options? Knowing that it's increased from 35mb to 1000mb+ only gets us so far, we need to know what those additional 965mb of data contain, are they all transients? Additionally, you never explained what your code block means, e.g. does `fusion_builder_settings 276072` mean that `fusion_builder_settings` appears 276072 times in the table? Or that it's 276kb? It's not obvious, nor is it clear how you got that data. Please update your question to make it clear! ( you can edit it with the edit link )

Comment: i am not an expert so idk where to look to see what that data is. wp_options
Uppercase: 0 Rows: 655 Size: 83.66MB

Comment: You'd need info about the table when it's big, the bigger the better. specifically option names. So for example if you list out the options and they all look like `banana_stuff1` `bannana_stuff2` then you know a plugin that uses the `banana_` prefix is the culprit. You could always just turn them all off then turn them on 1 by 1 to find the culprit. Eitherway right now this is a very open ended question, and once you've found the plugin the only things you can do on stack exchange are ask how to deactivate it or go to their support requests avenue anyway, we don't do 3rd party plugin support